# Displaying keyboard below the the selected line using multi-line TextField

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-textinputlayout

so I've got the following layout with the following  `TextInputEditText` :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/note"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_notes_24">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Right now, when I select to write inside the `TextInputEditText` the keyboard automatically displays below the `TextInputEditText`:
[image: belowtheedittext]

Now, what I want to is that rather displaying the keyboard below the `TextInputEditText`, I want the display to keyboard below the current "selected" line, which should look like this:
[image: belowtheline1]
[image: belowtheline2]

Example video how it should look like:
https://jumpshare.com/v/TAO6jo1jdnRZDhYyzrkY

How can this be solved in the right way?
I've tried using `android:windowsoftinputmode`, but I couldn't find the appropriate attribute.

I'm assuming there is not much leeway when it comes to the displaying the keyboard?